# MSChart showing axis in thousands

Tags: mschart

I need to present a chart with a Y Axis in MS Chart so that instead of showing 1000, 1500, 2000, it shows as 1K, 1.5K and 2K etc.

Can this be done, and can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the customize event of mschart.

```
private void chart1_Customize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var yAxisLabel in chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.CustomLabels)
    {
        label.Text = double.Parse(label.Text)/1000 + "K";
    }
}
```

This event is fired just before the chart image is drawn. This event should be used to customize the chart picture.

Comment: did this help you ??? Accepting this as an answer if it satisfies your question would be appreciated.